# How can I check if a string contains a specifig character with any digit in front of it in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I've got a question about my code(below). I'm trying to make a function to check if a string contains a gram unit. The code loops checks each string for a g with a digit in front of it. If it find this, it will loop backwards through the indices of the string until the index is not a digit. The code is working for me but I'm wondering how I can improve this code and if there is a better way to do this.

```
lines = ["100gr", "pack of 100 gram", "100 g", "great pack of 15 gram", "1 pack of 8", "3 oz = 85 g", "100",]

for lineIndex, line in enumerate(lines): # loop through lines
    line = line.lower() # make line lowercase
    line = "".join(line.split()) # delete whitespaces

    check = False

    for charIndex, char in enumerate(line): # loop through every index from string
        if char == "g" and line[charIndex-1].isdigit() == True: #check for a g with in front a digit
            index = charIndex - 1
            myList = []

            #loop until the index in front is not a digit 
            while True:
                if line[index].isdigit() == True: 
                    myList.append(line[index])
                    index -= 1
                else:
                    break

            # make a string from the list and print it
            myList.reverse()
            result = ""
            for letter in myList:   
                result += letter
            result += "g"
            print("Line: %s\nBecomes: %s" % (line, result))

            # make check False
            check = True


    if check is False:
        print("Line: %s\nDoes not contain grams" % (line))
```

Result of code:

[image: result of code]

Comment: Can you write the result here directly instead of a link to a image? Did that result come from this code?

Answer (score 1):

A *neat* expression (from the interpreter):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\s*(\d+)\s*g(?:r|ram)?s*\b', ' '.join(lines))
['100', '100', '100', '15', '85']
```

---

```
>>> for res in re.findall(r'\s*(\d+)(\s*)([^\d\s]+)?\b', ' '.join(lines)):
    print 'input:', ''.join(res)
    print 'ouput:', '%sg' % res[0] if res[2] in ['g', 'gr', 'gram'] else 'No gram unit'
...
input: 100gr
ouput: 100g
input: 100 gram
ouput: 100g
input: 100 g
ouput: 100g
input: 15 gram
ouput: 15g
input: 1 pack
ouput: No gram unit
input: 8 
ouput: No gram unit
input: 3 oz
ouput: No gram unit
input: 85 g
ouput: 85g
input: 100
ouput: No gram unit
```

Comment: you could improve this further by adding a word boundary at the end - at present this would match , e.g. `'200 green beans'`. How about `(\d+)\s*g(?:r|ram)?s*\b`

Comment: No worries, +1 for the most flexible answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using regexp?

```
import re

lines = ["100gr", "pack of 100 gram", "100 g", "great pack of 15 gram", "1 pack of 8", "3 oz = 85 g", "100"]

pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\s*g")

for line in lines:
    search = pattern.search(line)
    if search:
        print search.group()
```

returns:

```
100g
100 g
100 g
15 g
85 g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
map(lambda x: (x, map(lambda x: x+'g', re.findall('(\d+)\s*(?=g|gr|gm|gram)', x))) if re.search('(\d+)\s*(?=g|gr|gm|gram)', x) else (x, 'No gram unit'), lines)
```

This returns a list of tuple - `(<sentence>, [<quantity_in_grams>, ...])`

returns:

```
[('100gr', '100g'),
('pack of 100 gram', '100g'),
('100 g', '100g'),
('great pack of 15 gram', '15g'),
('1 pack of 8', 'No gram unit'),
('3 oz = 85 g', '85g'),
('3 oz = 85 g and 200 g', ['85g', '200g']),
('100', 'No gram unit')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could greatly reduce that with a regular expression, searching for at least one digit, followed by possible whitespace, followed by the letter "g":

```
import re

lines = ["100gr", "pack of 100 gram", "100 g", "great pack of 15 gram", "1 pack of 8", "3 oz = 85 g", "100",]
for line in lines:
    result = re.findall(r'\d+\s*g', line)
    if result:
        print(*result)
    else:
        print('Not found.')
```

The result:

```
100g
100 g
100 g
15 g
Not found.
85 g
Not found.
```